# How to fix jagged SVG xcassets image in SwiftUI iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, svg, swiftui

I'm trying to add an SVG image to my SwiftUI application and the edges around the image are jagged. How can I fix this?

I have verified that the actual SVG image is not jagged. I also tried adding `.interpolation(.none)` with no success. As well as enabling `Preserve Vector Data`, which didn't work either.

It almost looks like it's not treating the image as an SVG, because changing the foreground color property doesn't have any impact.

```swift
HStack {
    if let satelliteImage = UIImage(named: "satellite-dish-solid") {
        Image(uiImage: satelliteImage)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
    }
    Text("Satellite")
}
```

[image: SwiftUI Preview Showing Jagged Image]

[image: XCAsset Image Inspector]

Comment: Try rendering it as a template image and try preserving the vector qualities. This will increase size but should render as a symbol image like SF Symbols. Click the `Preserve Vector Data` option, and change `Render As` to symbol/template image.

Comment: @MrDeveloper That fixed the color issue I was mentioning. But it's still jagged.

Comment: OK. Is the issue possibly that the SVG is not a large enough file size? I see that it is 512x512. Maybe try upping that using a vector program to something such as 2048x2048? That could improve the SVG quality. Does it look fine when you open it in say Preview? Also, the SwiftUI `Image` type should work here - what if you tried just doing `Image("satellite-dish-solid")`?